# Convert int to hex byte value

Tags: java, hex, byte, arrays

I want to read block wise data of NFC tag. For which the command is a byte array and it needs block number.

```
public static byte[] readSingleBlockCmd(int blockNo) {
        byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
        cmd[0] = (byte) 0x02;//flag
        cmd[1] = (byte) 0x23;//cmd
        cmd[2]= (byte)blockNo;

        return cmd;

    }
```

> - How can I change the int blockNo to its hexadecimal value , which can be cast to byte .I want the byte value and not an byte []

I have gone through the following links

[Convert integer into byte array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936857/convert-integer-into-byte-array-java)

[How to autoconvert hexcode to use it as byte[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616233/how-to-autoconvert-hexcode-to-use-it-as-byte-in-java)

[Java integer to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183240/java-integer-to-byte-array)

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't your question answered by those links? If not, update your question to explain why and what you are having trouble with specifically.

Comment: Let's clear some things up: "Hexadecimal" is an encoding, specifically for how to write the number out as a String. 0x25 is hexadecimal encoded. But the number itself is still 37 (in base 10), and it is an int or a byte or whatever. You're not using any Strings here, so please forget about the "hexadecimal" part of your question and please ask again, because I don't know what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Converting an integer (in decimal) to hex can be done with the following line:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(blockNo);
```

Then to convert it to byte, you can use

```
Byte.parseByte(hex,16);
```

But if all you wanted to do is convert the parameter to bytes:

```
Byte.parseByte(blockNo);
```

would work too I guess. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Exactly, it's supposed to do nothing. it is the same as the last line that I mentioned. But since he wants a hexadecimal, I suggested that he could do it with the inbuilt function to convert to into a string.